# Creating a rule with a constant JSON parameter in AWS CDK (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm having trouble with my cloud deployment script for AWS, I've been trying to create a rule that triggers my lambda every 15 minutes and invoke it with a json object. If i were to do this from the console i'd do it like this:
[image]

After a long time i figured out how to configure this in code:

```
var functionInput = new { Command = command };
var input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(functionInput);
var target = new LambdaFunction(lambda, new LambdaFunctionProps
{
    Event = RuleTargetInput.FromObject(input)
});
```

Or like this:

```
var target = new LambdaFunction(lambda, new LambdaFunctionProps
{
    Event = RuleTargetInput.FromText("{\"Command\" = \"" + command + "\"}")
});
```

But the constant is not correct on aws, i have tried many different ways but it always turns out like this:

[image]

This is not correct Json and can't be parsed back to the class, so I want it to turn out like:
{"Command" = "CLEANUP"}

Comment: There's an open GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var inputDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
inputDict.Add("Command", "CleanUp");
myRule.AddTarget(new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.Targets.LambdaFunction(myFunction,
    new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.Targets.LambdaFunctionProps 
    { 
        Event = RuleTargetInput.FromObject(inputDict) 
    }));
```

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<string, object>` when some of the values in your JSON are other than strings

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for the Python equivalent for the same. Figured out finally - Hope someone find this helpful

```
    from aws_cdk import aws_events as events
    from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as lambda_
    
    event_input = {"some_key": "some_value"}


    some_lambda = lambda_.Function( 
                   # lambda construct
                  )

    some_rule = events.Rule(
                   # rule construct 
                  )

    some_rule.add_target(
        targets.LambdaFunction(
            some_lambda,
            event=events.RuleTargetInput.from_object(event_input)
        )
    )
```